# cp from Linux to CIFS (windows) share mount is very slow

Tags: cifs

I am wondering why cp command of 72GB data from linux server to a mounted CIFS (windows) share works too slow? It takes more then 3 hours already.

Is the any way to see where the gap, bottleneck?

P.S.

Both VM on XenServer 5.5 with 1GB NIC
Linux VM RHEL5.5; 4GB RAM; 4 CPU; 8GB SWAP
Windows VM Windows Server2008; 4GB RAM; 2 CPU

---

Are the two machines on the same ip subnet? - YES

What is the file structure like (lots of small files?) - YES

User mail boxes, /etc, /var/log what is the disk subsystem that these vm's are using? - VM are seating on iSCSI virtual disk storage which is SAN with iSCSI interface was formated with LVM support by itself.

dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt bs=1024k count=5000 - took about 5 minutes to create and copied it in a secs.

Looks like I have some problems with network interfaces.

Comment: What are these two computers connected to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

are the two machines on the same ip subnet?

what is the file structure like (lots of small files?)

what is the disk subsystem that these vm's are using?

if it is taking 3 hours then you are at about 7MB / per second

can you make a 1gb file and copy it to another part of the same disk on each of the vm's?

on windows you can create a 1gb file with the following command :

```
fsutil file createnew file.txt 1024000000
```

on linux :

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt bs=1k count=1000
```

this could tell you if it is the underlying disk system or the network config.

Comment: @VVP: Hey, you should add the answers to johnh's questions in your question.. not only is this the "right way" to do it, but it will bump the question thread so that more people will see it.